# Why is the notification "File is ready" pops up after every message on TeamSpeak 3 and is so big?

Tags: gnome, notification, interface

I recently installed Ubuntu in dual boot on my machine and I'm exploring this beautiful world step by step, however I have a weird problem.

[image: I will let the image speak]

Is there a way to fix the interface?

I would like to:

- Disable the notifications completely
- Move the notifications elsewhere
- Modify the size of the notification area

Let me know if it's possible... this is bugging me so much!

Comment: What is TeamSpeak? Is it related to Ubuntu? Does it have config options, ...like, "disable notifications"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use gnome extension [Window Is Ready Remover](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1007/window-is-ready-notification-remover/) to remove this annoying notifications.

Disadvantage of this solution is that this extension removes it for all programs (not all notifications, only "window is ready")

Comment: This is the correct solution.

Comment: This extension doesn't bring the "Open file" window to the front; it just silences the notification.